# What is the best way to ignore elements in a list assignment?

Tags: perl

I am using a list assignment to assign tab-separated values to different variables, like so:

```
perl -E '(my $first, my $second, my $third) = split(/\t/, qq[a\tb\tc]); say $first; say $second; say $third;'
a
b
c
```

To ignore a value, I can assign it to a dummy variable:

```
perl -E '(my $first, my $dummy, my $third) = split(/\t/, qq[a\tb\tc]); say $first; say $third;'
a
c
```

I don't like having unused variables. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [undef](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

(my $first, undef, my $third) = split(/\t/, qq[a\tb\tc]);
say $first; 
say $third;
```

Output:

```
a
c
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list slice:

```
my ($first, $third) = ( split(/\t/, qq[a\tb\tc]) )[0,2];
```

Like with an array slice, e.g. `@array[0,2]`, you can take a slice out of a list.

Comment: TMOWTDI, But I think I prefer making it explicit what I'm ignoring.

Comment: It's explicit that you are ignoring whatever is at index 1 :)

Comment: @Wes This is not less explicit.

Answer (score 2):

In `my` declarations, `undef` serves as a placeholder. Therefore,

```
my ($first, undef, $third) = split(/\t/, qq[a\tb\tc]);
```

is a simpler alternative to

```
(my $first, undef, my $third) = split(/\t/, qq[a\tb\tc]);
```

Comment: You may wish to be more obvious about what you are doing. To the unobservant eye it just looks like you copied the first answer.

Comment: Thanks Bork, I meant it to be a comment to the accepted answer but I must have clicked incorrectly.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but hey, people did like it.